# Как вызвать функцию из $js = <<<JS?

Tags: php

Функцию завернул в  $js = JS, и не знаю как вызвать функцию send()

```
    $js = <<<JS
  function send(){
      var data='Данные для отправки: '+Math.random();
      conn.send(data);
      console.log('Отправлено: '+data);
  }
JS;

    $this->registerJs($js);
?>

<button onclick="send();">Send</button>
```

Comment: что консоль выдает ?

Comment: @madfan41k index:139 Uncaught ReferenceError: send is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index:139)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во первых, JS-код нужно было поместить в контейнер `<script>...</script>`.
Во вторых, нужно было не сохранять в переменной, а выводить в браузер:

```
<?php

echo <<<JS
    <script>
        function send(){
            var data = 'Данные для отправки: ' + Math.random();
            conn.send(data);
            console.log('Отправлено: ' + data);
        }
    </script>
JS;

?>

<button onclick="send();">Send</button>
```

Comment: мы в onclick должны передать не результат вызваной функции, а функцию которую хотим вызвать: <button onclick="send">Send</button>

Comment: А что по вашему мнению в примере выше передаётся в onclick ?

Comment: По моему мнению в onclick передается результат функции send, и эта функция вызовется сразу же при рендере DOM, а не при нажатии на клавишу